# Not able to run test cases through maven

Tags: xml, maven, selenium-webdriver

I have pom.xml which contains dependancy
I have suite.xml in which i have given path to the .class file where test cases are listed.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="PCMS Project">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="com.tieto.pcms.Base.CustomListener" />
</listeners>
<test name="Suite Test case" preserve-order="true">
<classes>
<class name="com.tieto.pcms.TestCases.PCMS_Suite" ></class>  
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

When i run mvn clean compile it runs fine
but when i run mvn test it runs but not execute any of the test case showing below message

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: The name of your tests do not match the [default name pattern for unit tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) which should be named like `*Test.java`

Comment: changed to testcase name to *Test.java, still not working

Comment: Please give a full pom file..Furthermore why do you need the suite.xml file ?